# Не получается открыть проект со старым SDK в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, обработка-ошибок

Загрузил проект в формате zip, распаковали и попытался запустить, появилось следующее окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нажал на Convers, появилось окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажал OK, началась сборка, после которой в Android Studio возникла следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понимаю, проблема в том, что требуемая версия sdk не соответствует той, которая у меня, но как узнать какая версия нужна и что делать дальше, я не знаю

build.gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.glide"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'

    // RecyclerView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

    // volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    // glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: покажите `build.gradle`

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev, build.gradle добавил

Comment: Не тот, поищите внутри еще один файл, в проектах созданных в студии он находится в папке `app`. Он же ругается на строки `com.android.support*`

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev, готово

Comment: В первом `build.gradle` пропишите репозиторий гугла: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven. Обратите внимание на комментарий  - скорее всего вам понадобится тот кусок раскомментировать.

Comment: Следуйте инструкциям с вкладки `build`, при клике на определенную ошибку покажет возможные пути решения. Многое гуглится, но мне не понятно зачем вы используете такой старый пример? Посмотрите эту ссылку https://bumptech.github.io/glide/